# How to install man pages on an ubuntu docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, manpage

I use the following Dockerfile to build an image and start a container. But once I am in the container, I still can not find manpages. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt -y update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN apt-get -y install vim
RUN apt-get -y install man
RUN apt-get -y install gawk
RUN apt-get -y install mawk

$ man man
No manual entry for man
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
$ find /usr/share/man /usr/local/share/man  -type f
```

Comment: You need to install the `manpages` package if you want to have manpages available.

Answer (score 26):

You need to make a change to your `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes` within the container. You can do this in your Dockerfile with the following command:

```sh
RUN sed -i 's:^path-exclude=/usr/share/man:#path-exclude=/usr/share/man:' \
        /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes
```

Then make another update to your Dockerfile to install the man pages

```sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        man \
        manpages-posix
```

Comment: Avoid `/` as sed delimiter when working with path: 
`sed -i 's,^path-exclude=/usr/share/man/,#path-exclude=/usr/share/man/,' /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes`

Answer (score 12):

There is a easier way to enable the MAN command.

In terminal, just execute the command below:

> unminimize

It will ask if you like to continue [Y/n]
Just press:

> Y

It will take a while to finish all the processing.

After that, test this:

> man man

Simple as that

Thanks to [@kazushi](https://medium.com/@kazushi/use-man-pages-in-ubuntu-docker-containers-2485a7abf500)

Comment: That is not simple, how I press "Y" inside docker file?

Comment: For me, it needs to install man-db after `unminimize`: 
`root# apt install man-db`