# Man pages not being installed in python docker image

Tags: docker, apt, manpage

I am trying to extend a `python` docker image by installing some apt packages. However, I'm running into problems related to missing manual pages. Man pages don't seem to be getting installed  (even with `man-db` installed).

If I run the following:

```
docker run -it python:3.9-slim@sha256:2c018e29a8eada75e855d78641adda978a2c0a035fd928e281e1240144e8a337 /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y man-db
apt-get install -y zzuf
```

`dpkg` claims that it has installed some man pages (at least `-L` links them)

```
> dpkg -L zzuf | grep man1
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/zzat.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/zzuf.1.gz
```

But they don't seem to actually be installed (and `/usr/share/man` is empty)

```
> ls /usr/share/man
```

Why is this happening and how do I get manual pages to be installed?

## Feedback

[How to install man pages on an ubuntu docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152906/how-to-install-man-pages-on-an-ubuntu-docker-image) is addressing a problem with the same cause: `dpkg` can be configured to not install files matching certain packages.

Comment: You're highly unlikely to need the man pages to run your Python application, and they're disabled in the `dpkg` configuration.  While the linked question has details on this, it saves space to leave unnecessary files like this out of your image.

Comment: This was causing `default-jre` installation to fail because it expects certain manual directories to exist. So if you want to interface with any java code using python and docker this is likely to be an issue.